# Segmentation fault and warning in ROT13 implementation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm coding a function that implements rot13, I only make the case of a,b,...,m (+13), but I have a segmentation fault error and warning:

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char rot13(char palabra[]) { //char *palabra
    int y = (short) strlen(palabra);
    char abc[27]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (int i = 0; i < y ; ++i) {
        if(palabra[i]<'m' && palabra[i]>='a'){
            for (int j = 0; j <26 ; ++j) {
                if (palabra[i]==abc[j]){
                    palabra[i]=abc[j+13];
                }
            }    
        }    
    }

    return palabra;
}

int main() {
    rot13("aaa");
    return 0;
}
```

**WARNING:**

```
main.c:18:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return palabra;
```

I need help to understand the warning and how to solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: Your function says it returns a single `char` yet you're trying to return an array of `char`. You don't really need to return anything since you're modifying the array in place.

Comment: You’re still looping `j` from 0 to 25, even if you don’t allow letters over `'m'`. `abc[j + 13]` gets out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Another major problem is that **your code is trying to change a string literal** (the `"aaa"`) **which is considered undefined behavior in C**. Compilers are free to store string literals in a read-only memory region.

It's doing it in `palabra[i]=abc[j+13];`, where you overwrite each byte of the input parameter.

Comment: Not only a major problem but this is the true reason for the segfault. Well spotted!

Comment: so exist an alternative to code rot13 using string literals? or i have to use pointers obligatorily?

Comment: Just declare a variable as `char buffer[] = "something"`, and pass it to your function. You can safely write to `buffer` because it's not a string literal. Another option is to have a function like `char *rot13(char *output, size_t size, const char *input) { ... }`. You read from input, but write to output, and don't write more than `size` bytes to it (including the nul terminator).

Comment: nice, it worked! also i changed the function to void and fix parameter j, the function works, but the only thing that i cannot understand is in the case that i want to return the new char palabra[] (with ROT13). how i can do it?

Comment: you'll need to use `malloc` to allocate a new buffer, write bytes to it, and return it..

Comment: and later how i liberate this memory if i have to return that value?

Comment: Call `free(pointer)` in the function that called the `rot13`. But it's better to have those 3 arguments in the `rot13` function, so your `main` is responsible for allocating the buffer, and pass the correct size to `rot13`. When your function returns, `main` will have the result, and will also be responsible for deallocating the previously allocated result.

Comment: mm i cannot solve the problem yet:(, i use calloc to allocate a new pointer, and that pointer have the value that i want to return, but at the same time i have to set free the memory of the pointer that have the value... how i can do it? tyyy

Comment: Not sure I understand you. Can you show some code? Open a new question with it. FWIW, your function return the pointer, and after you use the value, you free it.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of your function is 'char', but you are attempting to return a char*.

Also, in this snippet:

```
for (int j = 0; j <26 ; ++j) {
    if (palabra[i] == abc[j]) {
        palabra[i] = abc[j+13];
    }
```

`abc` is an array with 27 elements.
Index `i` is 0.
The first 'a' is matched, and `palabra[0]` becomes 'n'.
`i` doesn't increment yet, but later within the same loop, palabra[0] == abc[13],
which causes `palabra[i] = abc[13+13]` (the terminating '\0').
Several iterations later, your debugger should show:

```
if(palabra[0] == abc[26]) {
    palabra[0] = abc[26 + 13]; //Segmentation Violation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen two problems so far.

The first one is in the line 10, which is `"palabra[i]=abc[j+13];"`. The **abc** array has a size of 27 elements, so this statement overflows its maximum size when j is higher than 13.

The second one is the returning of `char rot13(char palavra[])` function. This function expects the return of a char, but you are return an array instead.
Also, this function could be `void rot13(char palavra[])`, because you don't need to return anything, you are passing the array you are updating inside the function rot13.